# I can't play Pokemon GO! What's wrong?

Tags: technical-issues, pokemon-go

Pokemon GO isn't working at all for me right now. I'm in one of the following circumstances and can't do anything:

- My game is displaying a "Try Again" message
- I'm stuck on the Loading Screen
- When I sign in I get a message that the servers are experiencing problems.
- I see the map but nothing is loaded, and my team color is wrong
- The "loading" Pokeball just ends up spinning and I can't catch or interact with things
- When I try to catch a Pokemon, the Pokeball just sits on my screen doing nothing
- Gym opponents will drop to 1 HP and won't take any more damage or attack
- When I open a pokestop, the pokestop image and the name of the pokestop does not load.

What's causing this? Is there a way to fix it?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussions, this conversation has moved to [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42461/discussion-between-timelord64-and-kaz-wolfe).

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Most (if not all) of the problems listed in the question are related to the Pokemon GO servers being offline, slow to respond, or overloaded with requests.

In the meantime, nobody likes not playing the game. Fortunately, there are a few things you can do:

- **Just Wait**
  The easiest (and best) move to take is just to wait for the servers to restore to a normal state. You can check the server status [at this handy page](http://ispokemongodownornot.com/), or by just trying to log in to the game.
- **Force Quit the App**
  Sometimes, the app will get stuck in a cycle of failure and will be unable to actually do anything. You can fix this by [iOS] opening the Multitasking window and swiping up on Pokemon GO, or [Android] navigating to Settings > Apps > Pokemon GO and then touching the <kbd>Force Quit</kbd> button.
- **[Android] Clear Caches/Data**
  As a more extreme measure, you can go to Settings > Apps > Pokemon GO and tap the <kbd>Clear Data</kbd> button. Note that this will only delete your local data -- your Pokemon will be safe. However, you will need to log in again. Be sure you know what account you used/created for Pokemon GO if you do this.
- **Reinstall the App**
  If all else fails, you can just go the nuclear option and erase the entire app and start again. If you have an existing account (and you know the credentials used), your Pokemon will be at no risk and will all be there once you log in again.

Comment: Should probably talk about the restrict background data problem people had on Android. Restricting Google play store data would cause people to be unable to login.

Comment: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/278014/pokemon-go-wont-reload-without-wifi/278256#278256

Answer (score 6):

Potential solution for gps, is be sure your location is enabled.

- On iOS, go to settings > Privacy > location services > Pokemon Go

  - Make sure it is on for "While Using"
- On Android go to settings > location and security

  - Make sure location is enabled

Another solution(s) that have helped individuals that you may want to try is:

- Turn on Wifi
- Reset Network Settings
- Turn phone on/off

Answer (score 4):

Pokémon Go is frequently failing to login on my iPhone, same for my husband (Samsung) and even when we can login, on capturing or randomly, gym battles (1hp) etc, the game will just stop responding. We have WIFI call/WIFI in general also enabled on our phones.
Now, we do have bad carrier signal at our home (but excellent WIFI), so easy to blame that, but... This is also the case should we pop into town where carrier signals are very strong.

However, (**this may or may not get your Pokémon account banned**), using Nox app player, I'm able to login no problem via my PC using the very same internet connection I use on my phone. I experience little/no connection drops and no client freezing, just annoying that I can't ( or rather, choose not to for cheating sake) move my location in game.

Not sure why, maybe someone can poke into this as it doesn't appear the servers are really all that 'slow to respond' and crippled on a frequent basis as is being advertised. It feels like the mobile platform in general has some kind of flaw preventing stable connections.

Comment: Heads up that even logging in ONCE on an emulator will flag your account for review. I suggest you tread very lightly in the future.

Comment: Been emulating for a few days now, no bans, not sure if the ban system is just overloaded or that accounts that are being reviewed showing no real 'abuse' of the system are being ignored. But yeh, if you value your account, probably best not to emulate it.

Comment: @Draylynn ban systems almost never have an immediate effect. Usually first your account is flagged for review, then an investigation runs its course, THEN if found guilty you get banned (usually in waves along with other cheaters). So a few days isn't a significant reference period. If you value your account don't use cheats, that's all.

Answer (score 1):

The game is relatively new, and Niantic probably didn't think the game would be *that* popular, as the servers are unstable as of now.

They're also releasing it on lots and lots of countries, which helps a lot.

Those problems you described are just symptoms of that - the servers just can't answer in enough time, as they also have to deal with millions of other people.

The servers are (obviously) getting more and more stable though.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me too. If you have been using a GPS spoof or been soft banned many times, then it is likely you have been banned permanently, on the device, not on the account, however.

If you haven't ever been soft banned before and you haven't used a GPS spoof at all ever, then it's probably a problem with the servers. Either:

1. Close the app and try again.
2. Power off your device then try again.
3. Uninstall, install it then try again.
4. Check your GPS is turned on and WiFi is connected/Mobile Data is turned on.
5. Wait a few hours then try again.

If none of those things work, then you've probably been banned, so you should install Pokemon Go on another device, log into the same account and try again. If even that fails, on the device you just tried to log into that account on, create a new account and start over.

Comment: That's exactly what the accepted answer says, isn't it?