# How do I log back in to Pokemon go?

Tags: pokemon-go

My Pokemon go logged me out and I tried using the same email I used to login when I first started, but it did not work? How do I get my account back?

Comment: What did not work? You were not able to login? Or it logged you in and created a new character? What happened after you tried to login?

Comment: note that the game is highly unstable right now and it may not be anything to do with you. See [this question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/274535/i-cant-play-pokemon-go-whats-wrong)

Answer (score 0):

This just happened to me, and it recently just started working again. What I did was just wait. And I was very impatient so I started to check like every 5 or so mins and I took a Break from my phone. Then, after my 15min break, it started working again! Hopefully this helped :)