# Why can't I add Pokemon into a Gym?

Tags: pokemon-go

When adding a Pokemon into a gym, it says 'Error' and kicks me out.  My Pokemon are at full health, I've tried with different Pokemon, but still nothing.  Can anyone help?

---

Update: It's working now, however it's not the same as some other questions because I'm still able to use Pokestops and capture Pokemon.  Just not gyms.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I can't play Pokemon GO! What's wrong?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/274535/i-cant-play-pokemon-go-whats-wrong)

Comment: Sometimes this can be because another player has already filled the spot/the gym is under attack and the tier was lost. Re-load the gym and see. Alternatively, make sure you are within range of the gym.

Comment: @TimMalone definetly not a duplicate of that. OP's problem isn't the same, they can still do everything, but they got an error when they tried adding a Pokemon. The reason for it is not due to server issues as the answers in that question suggest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had this happen to me several times. It is possibly due to someone else having placed a Pokemon in the gym before you while you were trying to place one.

This causes an error because the gym is now of a different colour or all it's spots are full.

Answer (score 1):

Restart the app. Chances are you'll find you can't place a pokemon in there anymore either due to the gym changing colors or another trainer on your team placed their pokemon in the open slot.