# Why is the Pokestop onlly showing white with no name?

Tags: pokemon-go

When I go into a Blue Pokestop, it just turns white. It also doesn't have a name.

What's up with that?

[image: pokestop is not loading]

Comment: that means the server was overloaded and your app couldn't download the stop information. just try again.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I can't play Pokemon GO! What's wrong?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/274535/i-cant-play-pokemon-go-whats-wrong)

Comment: Could you add a screenshot to show us what you are experiencing?

Answer (score 1):

This is caused by the poke stop not being loaded yet. There can be multiple reasons for this:
Your connection might be slow or the servers are having issues (which they are known to have often). If you are playing at prime times (when everyone else is playing) this is most likely why they are not loading.

When this happens to me i either wait for a better signal or walk around a bit (you might be standing in a place with bad connection), or i restart the app.