# Pokémon go technical issues

Tags: pokemon-go

Can azumi A40c not run Pokémon go??  it closes itself on the garados loading screen, i have tried older versions and there either give the service humble accept messege , please help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I can't play Pokemon GO! What's wrong?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/274535/i-cant-play-pokemon-go-whats-wrong)

Comment: @pppery That question is more on connection issues, while this is a hardware problem that is not really connection-related.

Answer (score 2):

[This](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/you-might-need-upgrade-phone-pokemon-go/) article says Pokemon Go requires 2gb of RAM, while [this](http://www.handy.bg/en/p/azumi/azumi-a40-c) phone spec of your phone say it has 521mb, which is no-where near the requirement. Sorry, but I don't think your phone can run it.