# How to login into PewDiePie's Tuber Simulator?

Tags: pewdiepie-tuber-simulator

I did one of the following and can't play PewDiePie's Tuber simulator with the progress linked to my account:

- I logged out and can't login
- I logged out and tried to login in another device
- I tried to login on a second device without logging out
- My device broke and I can't login from another one
- I restarted my device / reinstalled the game and my progress didn't save

And possibly even:

- I don't know how to login
- I forgot my login name and password

How can I fix each of these problems, and can I prevent them somehow?

Comment: Can you not just add that answer to the one that the others are duped to?  Do we really need another question?

Comment: @Frank, sorry for the delay, but I'd like to say that *all* the questions around this topic are about a single element of the list above, and none of the questions about this are duped, since no single one has an answer, just this one. By covering all different sub-questions that may haven't been closed as dupes to an answered question we get things more organized.

Comment: This is the only one with the answer because you asked a new question instead of answering one of the existing ones.

Comment: Were you trying to emulate [Kaz's post for Pokémon Go](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/274535/162442)? If so, it really was unnecessary for this game and I agree with Frank that you should just answer the preexisting questions. Doing this does not make the site more organized. The sheer volume of Pokémon Go questions made the other somewhat desireable but as of right now, Pewdiepie's Tuber Simulator has 27 questions as opposed to Pokémon Go's over 1400.

Comment: @Vemonus Thanks for sharing your opinion, unlike other users. The reason I posted this was because there are 15 out of 27 questions on PDS that are dupes of each other, but don't have an answer.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

According to the developers (contract them for more detailed information via email), you can retrieve your save game data by logging in to your account, and linking it if it's a new device. There also is a fallback option if you lost you login info. This is a part of  an email I got in reply from them:

> If
>    you linked your game with your Google Play or Game Center account, you can get it back in the social menu, just after you go through the short tutorial after you choose NEW GAME.  Be very careful not to set a new channel name as it will erase your old account.
>
> Click
>    on Link Account and follow the instructions by saying this is your NEW DEVICE.  Your account should now be able to connect to the online features as well.
>
> The
>    Link account/new device process specifically uses the last account made in either Google Play or the Game Center. If there was another account added afterwards, that will be the account used.
>
> Only
>    one account can be linked to Google Play or Game Center.
>   The
>    newest account overwrites the previous.
>
> If
>    no account is linked, there is no account to recover.
>
> Please
>    note that if you cheated and/or tried to change the date to progress faster, you will be brought back to the moment before the time change.
>
> Please
>    make sure you’ve updated to the latest version.
>   It
>    is very important to do so as any account not updated will not be able to connect online anymore.
>
> All
>    update info will be available on our official Twitter page.
>   https://twitter.com/outerminds