# The game won't work on my wifi after a new router installed

Tags: pokemon-go

My Pokemon Go worked great on wifi or on cell data.

However, I installed a new TP brand router at my house and an extender (not sure if that is important).  I named the router exactly the same as my old router so most my equipment would automatically pick it up.

My phone sees the new router, hooks to it, works great and I have a download of over 30-50MB per second.  However, since I changed Pokemon Go will never log-in on wi-fi.  Always stops at the login screen and asks to "retry".  If I turn wifi off, it starts right up.

Been doing this for a week since I've installed the new router.  What can be causing this? I have an android phone.

Comment: I realize the obvious is that my router is not connected to the internet, but trust me, it is.

Comment: A firewall is the likely reason.

Comment: I'm not a firewall router expert.  why would a new router just block a single application?  Everything else I've used with my phone and PC seem to work just fine through the new router.  I thought maybe it was pokemon thinking I'm "botting or something weird and not letting me log in.

Comment: Have you tried to see if turning off wifi on your phone will let you connect to check that it's not a problem with the app or its server and not your phone or router?

Comment: Yes, if I turn the wi-fi off, it always connects the first time.  Like I said, this is not a one time issue.  Happens every morning since I've installed the new router (5 days now).  I normally log in first thing in the morning to collect my coins and stardust.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I can't play Pokemon GO! What's wrong?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/274535/i-cant-play-pokemon-go-whats-wrong)

Comment: @pppery Seems like this is a unique issue relevant to TP-link routers. Not sure if that's counted as on-topic for Arqade, though.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem. We have a TP-Link router and one of our 3 phones can't log in with our home wifi.
The said phone logs in fine on mobile data or a shared wifi-hotspot from another device.
After reading your post I realised the problem must be between the device and our router. Turns out I was right!
Log into your router, and under network settings you should be able to "release" and then "renew" your routers IP-address. That solved the issue for me!